# How to deploy Help & Training from one org to another in salesforce?

Tags: deployment, metadata, sandbox, ant, customization

I have added some resources/links under help & training section in one org. I am looking to deploy this customization to another org. How can I achieve this?. Which metadata component I should refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [CustomHelpMenuSection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/) in the Metadata API docs v45.0.

I’ve not tested if this is exposed for Change Sets yet. If not, consider using Salesforce CLI or an IDE to retrieve and deploy the metadata.

Comment: I tried with the CustomHelpMenuSection metadata and it is working. Thanks for the answer @Doug Ayers